# printf crashes the program

Tags: c, crash, printf

I am using `sprintf` to convert `int` to string and then if I use `printf` the program crashes otherwise it works fine. Can anyone tell me the reason?

```
typedef char* string;
buffer[8] = (string*)malloc(sizeof(string));
buffer[8] = sprintf(buffer[8],"%d",inf[i].mPermissions);
```

It's working fine until here but when I print it like this:

```
printf("%s",buffer[8]);
```

...my program crashes.

Comment: If you don't share some code: No. Oh, and you should be using `snprintf` instead of `sprintf`

Comment: Do you have anymore info. How are you exactly using sprintf. What error do the crash gives? Are you running a debugger and seeing what error is thrown?

Comment: Please include some example code with your question. "printf crashes" doesn't say anything about the problem.

Comment: The reason is - you are doing something wrong. What - impossible to say without seeing actual code.

Comment: I will happily vote to reopen this question after it has the code that crashes in it. As many have said, it is difficult to debug a problem blindly. Wearing my mind-reading hat, I will guess that you have failed to call `sprintf` correctly, such that it has written all over your stack and generally caused Undefined Behavior. Once you have invoked UB, anything can happen. You got lucky and the program crashed. It is *much* worse if it appears to work for a while... then crashes in an unrelated section of code.

Comment: @Shweta: I see you've updated your question with a code example. The code example you've given leads me to believe that you don't know C very well. What is `sizeof(string)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
typedef char* string;
```

The C language has no string type. A char pointer is not the same thing as an allocated string.

```
buffer[8]=(string*)malloc(sizeof(string));
```

Why are you setting item number 9 in buffer to a string? (C is zero-indexed, so 0-8 = 9 items). Is that an array of pointers? Perhaps you meant to allocate a buffer of 8 characters?

It doesn't make any sense to typecast the result from malloc in the C language. In C++ you would have to do a cast.

You are allocating the size of a pointer, not the size of a buffer.

```
buffer[8]=sprintf(buffer[8],"%d",inf[i].mPermissions);
```

The first argument to sprintf must be an allocated buffer, not a character (one item of a buffer).

```
printf("%s",buffer[8]);
```

You are trying to print a string, but passing an item of a buffer (a character).

---

To sum this up, I would strongly recommend reading the first chapters of a C language book regarding *arrays and pointers* before attempting any form of string handling or dynamic memory allocation. If you don't know how something works, don't take a chance at the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

My bet is you're not allocating the buffer sprintf is writing into.

You need something like:

```
int myNumber = 42;
char myBuffer[12];
sprintf(myBuffer, "%d", myNumber);
```